# Where do I define my const array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization

I'm writing some C and I have a lookup table of ints. I'm a little rusty... where do I declare and initialize the array so that I can use it in multiple C files? Can I declare it in an H file and initialize it in a C file?

Comment: Is this question worth keeping up or should I delete it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Globals should be declared in a .h file and should be declared as `extern`, and then they should be defined in a .c file.  See [What's the best way to declare and define global variables and functions?](http://c-faq.com/decl/decldef.html) from the comp.lang.c FAQ.

For arrays, some extra care might be necessary.  See [Q1.24](http://c-faq.com/decl/extarraysize.html) from the comp.lang.c FAQ too.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, yes, you can do it. Read something about

```
extern static
```

keywords.

Comment: Thanks, that's the hint I needed.

Comment: I think the OP means "static" in a way, that doesn't correlate well with the meaning of the keyword `static` in the C language :).

Comment: i've posted both as they both refer to visibility of a variable in C language - extern scope to oher files or make it static in file it appears.

Answer (score 2):

You define the array in one C file, and declare it as extern in another.

One common mistake is to equate the array with a pointer, and do something like:

```
// file1.c:
int array[] = { 1,2,3,4};

// file1.h:
extern int *array;

// file2.c:
#include "file1.h"

// use array
```

This will *not* work. You can treat the name of an array as a pointer in some situations, but this is *not* one of them. [Edit: The right thing to do is something like:

```
 // file1.h:
 extern int array[];
```

Comment: But it works if you change `extern int *array;` to `extern int array[];`.

Comment: @R: right -- now that you mention it, it probably isn't so good that my answer talks about what to avoid, but *not* how to do it right.

Comment: "so good" is a subjective thing, but if you didn't edit, you wouldn't get my upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

You can declare it in a header file with `extern`, and define it in one of your source files.  However, by definition, it can't also be `static`.